# Excel VBA code to choose a specific column

Tags: vba

I have code that works well at moving to the next column based on what is entered, only when it gets to Column 13 I need it to start at the last row and work its way back. Can someone help me?

```
Dim lastrow As Long     
If Target.Column > 2 Then
     lastrow = Range("A17").Value
     'lastrow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlDown).Row
    If Target.Column Mod 2 = 1 Then 
        If Target.Row >= lastrow Then         
            Me.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Select
        Else             
            Me.Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Select
        End If
    Else       
        If Target.Row = 3 Then      
            Me.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Select
        Else          
            Me.Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Select
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: can you elaborate not sure what you mean

Comment: maybe you need xlUp instead of xlDown `lastrow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: This is on an Excel spreadsheet.  It works fine with the Column MOD function but need it to go up while on Column 13  .  Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though the issue is with your statement:

```
If Target.Column Mod 2 = 1 Then
```

I believe you are looking for the modulus operator for excel vba "\". Try this:

```
If (Target.Column\2) = 1 Then
```

Per your comment, try adding this code for column 13:

```
If Target.Column = 13 Then
'<your code here'
```

This should do the trick.

Also, you may want to use the Offset function. The syntax is .Range("").(RowOffset, ColumnOffset). This allows you to offset from a fixed position.

See fully edited code below:

```
If Target.Column > 2 Then
 lastrow = Range("A17").Value
 'lastrow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlDown).Row
If Target.Column Mod 2 = 1 Then 
    If Target.Row >= lastrow Then         
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Select
    Else             
        Me.Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Select
    End If
ElseIf Target.Column = 13 Then
    ' I am assuming the code below is what you need
    ' this would start at your last row and work it's way up
    Me.Cells(lastrow, Target.Column).Select
    For i = lastrow to 1 Step - 1 ' replace 1 with however far up you want it to  go
        Me.Cells(i, Target.Column).Select
    Next
Else       
    If Target.Row = 3 Then      
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Select
    Else          
        Me.Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column).Select
    End If
End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for that input.  Let me try to clear up what I am looking for.  The code works fine.  Really no issues.  I just want to add to the code something like If target.Column Mod 2=1 Or Target.Column <> 13 Then      Would that work?

Comment: I dont see why it wouldn't work based on the code. As long as Target.Column is being set properly, you should be able to return the .Column value (index position) and use that number as needed.

I also highly recommend just trying it out on your own, and if something doesn't work try to figure out why it isnt working. VBA is thankfully a really easy language to learn. You can learn a lot of how it works by trying (and failing) but figuring out where you went wrong.

Comment: ok, thank you Brandon.  I have made many attempts using the code I provided.  I tried your code and it works like my code works.  They both work to make the cursor go up on even rows and down on odd rows.  The issue or addition I was trying was that when it got to column 13 I want the cursor to move the other way  I have tried a few things and I just can't figure it out.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Wait, you just want the cursor to go up on column 13? Just add an ElseIF statement for Column 13. See my edited response.

Comment: I added an ElseIf block that first selects the lastrow in column 13, and then loops all the way up to 1, selecting each cell on it's way.

Keep in mind, this is still incredibly inefficient and it would be best to learn about arrays :).